# A shared resource for an object

Tags: c++

Say I have this class called Dog. Every dog has a different name but the same barking voice (which is loaded from a resource file).

```
class Dog {
public:
    Dog(const string &name) : _name(name) {
        _barkingVoice.load();
    }
    ~Dog() {
        _barkingVoice.free();
    }

    string getName() const { return _name; }
    void bark() { _barkingVoice.play(); }

private:
    string _name;
    VoiceResource _barkingVoice;
};
```

I want to call `_barkingVoice.load()` only if the instance of Dog is the first one, and `_barkingVoice.free()` only if there are no more instances of Dog.

The obvious solution is to set _barkingVoice as static and keep a reference counter of Dog as a data member.

My question is if there's an easier way to do this. Maybe an std implementation or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a reusable class to encapsulate the reference counting:

```
template<class ResourceType, class OwnerType>
class RefCounted {
public:
    RefCounted()          { if (++_refCount == 1) _resource.load(); }
    virtual ~RefCounted() { if (--_refCount == 0) _resource.free(); }
    ResourceType& operator*()  { return  _resource; }
    ResourceType* operator->() { return &_resource; }
private:
    static unsigned _refCount;
    static ResourceType _resource;
};

template<class T, class U> unsigned RefCounted<T, U>::_refCount = 0;
template<class T, class U> T RefCounted<T, U>::_resource;

class Dog {
public:
    Dog(const string &name) : _name(name) { }

    string getName() const { return _name; }
    void bark() { _barkingVoice->play(); }

private:
    string _name;
    RefCounted<VoiceResource, Dog> _barkingVoice;
};
```

Every template instantiation will have their own `_refCount` and `_resource`.

The second template parameter is to handle cases where you instantiate `RefCounted` with the same `ResourceType` but want to have separate reference counting for those instantiations. E.g. if you add a `Cat` class and want it to have its own `Refcounted<VoiceResource>`:

```
class Cat {
    // ...
private:
    RefCounted<VoiceResource, Cat> _meowingVoice;
};
```

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, why `VoiceResource` is not static? If it's shared between all instances of `Dog`, it should be. Else, you will need to load or copy the resuorce at every constructor call.

Have a static variable `static int instanceCount;`, that is set to `0`. In every casual, copy and move (C++11) constructor increment it, in destructor decrement it. That will give you opportunity to do what you wanted.

That will basicly work like `shared_ptr<T>` does, the might be a way to use it here instead of writing your own code, I just can't figure that out.

```
class Dog {
public:
    Dog(const string &name) : _name(name) {
        loadResource();
    }
    Dog(const Dog& b) : name(b.name) {            
        loadResource();
    }
    // only C++11:
    Dog(Dog&& b) : name(std::move(b.name))  {
        loadResource();
    }

    ~Dog() {
        freeResource();
        _barkingVoice.free();
    }

    string getName() const { return _name; }
    void bark() { _barkingVoice.play(); }

private:
    string _name;
    static VoiceResource _barkingVoice;
    static int instanceCount;

    static void loadResource() {
        if (instanceCount == 0) {
            _barkingVoice.load();
        }
        ++instanceCount;
    }
    static void freeResource() {
        --instanceCount;
        if (instanceCount == 0) {
            _barkingVoice.free();
        }
    }
};
int Dog::instanceCount = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question is if there's a shorter way of doing this. I don't want to write all that code again and again for similar classes.

Comment: @Pilpel consider having a Reource Manager that will return you a `shared_ptr<>` to a requested resource. That will be a lot clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Make `_barkingVoice` a `std::shared_ptr<VoiceResource>`.

A `shared_ptr` does exactly what you need: uses references counting to track the deletion of the last object, when it will deallocate the resource.

Comment: That's good, but if we create `Dog d("")`, we will still need to find already created resource. `shared_ptr` will only help with copying/moving.

Comment: True. I guess this doesn't work. Seems like we must implement the reference counting manually, like in Lapshin Dmitry's answer.